# Infinite alert boxes on Safari (iPad with IOS7)

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, alert

I've been testing some JavaScript code with a for loop that iterates a 1000 times and each loop will trigger a window.alert.

Now I was expecting a 'Prevent additional popups' checkbox. But after 150 times of pressing OK i'm losing hope. Is there some way to really kill an app? I've also considered reinstalling Safari, but Apple won't allow me to even uninstall the damn browser.

Is there a way out? While waiting for answers I'll keep pressing OK 850 more times...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearing the browsing history solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime, Command-Option-Escape should allow you to force-quit Safari and stop dealing with popups.

In the long term, can you post the code, or the offending part of it, so we can figure out why it's going bonkers?

Comment: Ah forgot to mention it's on iPad. The actual problem I'm trying to solve is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20380187/javascript-scroll-event-not-firing-on-iphone-with-ios7

Comment: To force-quit on iOS 7 you double-tap the home button, then swipe the window you want to force-quit upward off the screen.